# Regex Group Optional

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression that isn't working the way I thought it would.

```
("^\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?\\.\\d{2}(\\.\\d{2-4})?$");
```

I am trying to match a string that starts with either 2 or 4 digits, followed by a period, followed by 2 digits and then optionally another period and either 2 or 4 digits.

I would expect 33.44.4444 to work, as would 33.33 but anytime I have a string that has a 2nd period, my expression fails.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First thing to note: use verbatim string literals for regular expressions in C#, then you can ditch all those doubled backslashes :) Could you rewrite this as a [mcve]? It should be trivial to do - just a console app that creates the regex and shows a match that you'd expect to work. Anyone can do it, but it's helpful if only *one* person needs to do the typing, and everyone else can copy and paste...

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct for what you want to do except for the {2-4} part, if you use {2,4} it will go for the 2 to 4 characters capture you're looking for.

```
("^\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?\\.\\d{2}(\\.\\d{2,4})?$");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `\\d{2,4}` accepts three-digit numbers as well. It looks like OP wants to accept two or four, but not three.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out the syntax {2-4} is incorrect. Use {2,4} to specify a range of occurrences. But also if you only want 2 or 4 (not 3) I would use this regex:

```
@"^(\d{2}|\d{4})\.\d{2}(\.(\d{2}|\d{4}))?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)?$
```

`\d{2-4}` will match `{2-4}` text literally.

[RegEx Demo](http://fiddle.re/69kb7a)

Answer (score 0):

The way you expressed "either two or four digits" in the first section of your expression is correct:

```
\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?
```

The second part does it incorrectly:

```
(\\.\\d{2-4})?
```

Copy the first part into the second to fix the problem:

```
("^\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?\\.\\d{2}(\\.\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?)?$");
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/sY9nJ4/1)